# I appear online on Windows Live Messenger when my devices are turned off

Tags: windows-live-messenger, chat, microsoft-account

A friend has recently brought to my attention that I permanently appear online on the Windows Live Messenger chat network, even when all of my devices are turned off. The only software and services using my WLM account (that I am aware of) are `Trillian` (chat app I use and which also connects to my Skype account), `Skype for Windows 8` and `Outlook.com`. None of these should have me appear online when all of my devices are turned off.

Other potentially relevant info:

- I never receive messages sent to me in those times where my devices are turned off but I still appear online
- When actually running some chat software, instant messaging via WLM works fine
- There has also been no suspicious activity on my Microsoft account.
- My Microsoft account has 3-4 associated email adresses and I've switched the primary one a couple of times

Any idea what could be causing this or how I could better diagnose it?